# how do I modify an element with text received from input, and how do I stop the disable input if a character terminator is used?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm learning jQuery and having trouble figuring something out.
What I need to do is display an alert or note (I used h3) to a user to input their name followed by # (the character terminator). Anything the user types prior to the # symbol should change the text of a span element with id userName, in the heading. After the # is typed no other text should able to be typed. I wanted to have to ghost writer effect of the user typing out their naming in the header, but I couldn't figure that out so I put an input field in. I'm trying to use the if statement to append the keyspressed to the id, or otherwise stop the text from being input.

This is what I have:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').on(function() {
   $('input').keypress(function(evt) {
   var keyPressed=String.fromCharCode(evt.which); 
    if (keyPressed !== '#') 
   {
        $("userNameInput").append('userName');

    }
    else {
        return false;   
    }
    });
    });
    });
```

html:

```
           <header>
            <h1>Lab 6</h1>
            <h2>Welcome, <span id="userName">User!</span></h2>
            <h3>Please enter your name followed by # i.e. John#</h3>
            <input id="userNameInput" type="text">
           </header>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a bunch of issues... I *think* this is what you were going for though:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lhj218pe/)

HTML:

```
<h1>Lab 6</h1>
<h2>Welcome, <span id="userName">User</span>!</h2>
<h3>Please enter your name followed by # i.e. John#</h3>
<input id="userNameInput" type="text">
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var appendName = function(evt) {
    var keyPressed = String.fromCharCode(evt.which);
    if (keyPressed !== '#') {
      $("#userName").text(this.value + keyPressed);
    } else {
      $(this).off();
    }
  };
  $('#userNameInput').on("keypress", appendName);
});
```

You could also just disable the input field instead of turning off the listener if you wanted... just change  `$(this).off();` to `$(this).prop("disabled",true);`

---

Some problems that I noted in your code were... it looks like you were trying to just do a keypress event, but you had that nested in an `on`, and the `on` had no event type. This didn't really make sense but I assume you just wanted the keypress event listener.

This chunk here `$("userNameInput").append('userName');` was saying to look for an `<userNameInput>` and append the string `userName` to it.

You ignored `#` but did nothing to stop any new input afterwards.